# Ubuntu software center not show packages in fonts category

Tags: software-center

It not show anything in font category. I try to update, restart, deleted cache but it's not work.

Image: [image]

Thank you.

Comment: Write an answer.

Comment: Hi Sweetlove, please do not add answers to a question, you might answer your own question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this command, which fixed the problem:

```
sudo update-apt-xapian-index
```